# Using awk to create a KML file from another KML file

Tags: awk

Trying to take a very large KML file (sample.kml) of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="tl_2010_19013_tabblock10" id="tl_2010_19013_tabblock10">
    <SimpleField name="STATEFP10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="COUNTYFP10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="TRACTCE10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="BLOCKCE10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="GEOID10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NAME10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="MTFCC10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="UR10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="UACE10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="UATYP10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="FUNCSTAT10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ALAND10" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="AWATER10" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="INTPTLAT10" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="INTPTLON10" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>tl_2010_19013_tabblock10</name>
<Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#tl_2010_19013_tabblock10">
        <SimpleData name="STATEFP10">19</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="COUNTYFP10">013</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="TRACTCE10">002700</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="BLOCKCE10">2051</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GEOID10">190130027002051</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME10">Block 2051</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MTFCC10">G5040</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="UR10">R</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="FUNCSTAT10">S</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ALAND10">3890</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="AWATER10">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="INTPTLAT10">+42.4779525</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="INTPTLON10">-092.2489677</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-92.248857,42.476255 -92.248998,42.476256 -92.24906,42.479886 -92.248968,42.479915 -92.248857,42.476255</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#tl_2010_19013_tabblock10">
        <SimpleData name="STATEFP10">19</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="COUNTYFP10">013</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="TRACTCE10">002800</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="BLOCKCE10">3066</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GEOID10">190130028003066</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME10">Block 3066</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MTFCC10">G5040</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="UR10">R</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="FUNCSTAT10">S</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ALAND10">2669021</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="AWATER10">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="INTPTLAT10">+42.3771200</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="INTPTLON10">-092.1523795</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-92.142669,42.369695 -92.152457,42.369649 -92.155691,42.369641 -92.157833,42.369636 -92.1613,42.369628 -92.162245,42.369626 -92.162143,42.376605 -92.162074,42.380176 -92.162012,42.383357 -92.162,42.383994 -92.161987,42.38463 -92.142533,42.384571 -92.142555,42.382183 -92.142614,42.376921 -92.142638,42.373725 -92.142669,42.369695</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#tl_2010_19013_tabblock10">
        <SimpleData name="STATEFP10">19</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="COUNTYFP10">013</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="TRACTCE10">002800</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="BLOCKCE10">3114</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GEOID10">190130028003114</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME10">Block 3114</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MTFCC10">G5040</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="UR10">R</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="FUNCSTAT10">S</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ALAND10">3812216</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="AWATER10">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="INTPTLAT10">+42.3221995</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="INTPTLON10">-092.1314948</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-92.113071,42.317871 -92.113062,42.317839 -92.113063,42.317808 -92.113075,42.317769 -92.113076,42.31773 -92.11311,42.317621 -92.113131,42.317598 -92.113131,42.317559 -92.113154,42.317536 -92.113166,42.317497 -92.113272,42.317373 -92.113339,42.31728 -92.113361,42.317218 -92.113374,42.317147 -92.113376,42.317022 -92.113355,42.316991 -92.113346,42.31696 -92.113325,42.316935 -92.113275,42.316849 -92.113159,42.316746 -92.11315,42.316718 -92.113105,42.316663 -92.113051,42.316607 -92.112996,42.316566 -92.112942,42.316517 -92.112897,42.316461 -92.11287,42.316406 -92.112863,42.316316 -92.112865,42.316248 -92.112885,42.316159 -92.112914,42.316104 -92.112952,42.31605 -92.113019,42.315968 -92.11303,42.315885 -92.113018,42.315867 -92.11579,42.316047 -92.11661,42.316018 -92.116927,42.315869 -92.117785,42.315208 -92.118495,42.314244 -92.118563,42.31403 -92.118608,42.313551 -92.118464,42.313239 -92.117058,42.312234 -92.116791,42.31199 -92.11677,42.311607 -92.117186,42.311219 -92.117344,42.311119 -92.117952,42.310486 -92.118048,42.310488 -92.118213,42.310499 -92.118289,42.310491 -92.118365,42.310463 -92.118404,42.310454 -92.118456,42.310436 -92.118532,42.310418 -92.118609,42.31039 -92.118648,42.310382 -92.118801,42.310327 -92.11884,42.310309 -92.118877,42.310299 -92.119032,42.310226 -92.119109,42.310199 -92.119145,42.310199 -92.119311,42.310161 -92.119376,42.310154 -92.119415,42.310155 -92.119452,42.310146 -92.119491,42.310146 -92.119541,42.310126 -92.11958,42.310119 -92.119619,42.3101 -92.119656,42.310092 -92.119695,42.310073 -92.120094,42.309954 -92.120161,42.309922 -92.120184,42.309897 -92.120228,42.309881 -92.120248,42.309861 -92.120388,42.309791 -92.120434,42.309783 -92.120479,42.309767 -92.120659,42.309719 -92.120693,42.309703 -92.120739,42.309695 -92.120773,42.309679 -92.120862,42.309655 -92.120898,42.309638 -92.120953,42.309631 -92.120998,42.309615 -92.121134,42.309583 -92.121224,42.309568 -92.12128,42.309552 -92.121369,42.309536 -92.121416,42.30952 -92.12146,42.309512 -92.121786,42.309482 -92.121989,42.309444 -92.122091,42.30942 -92.122169,42.309396 -92.122216,42.309388 -92.122249,42.309371 -92.122294,42.309364 -92.122327,42.309348 -92.122374,42.30934 -92.122418,42.309341 -92.122463,42.309333 -92.122507,42.309342 -92.122553,42.309359 -92.122641,42.309376 -92.122831,42.309396 -92.122877,42.309413 -92.122921,42.309421 -92.122954,42.309438 -92.122976,42.309464 -92.123121,42.309498 -92.123365,42.309475 -92.12341,42.309465 -92.123438,42.309444 -92.123511,42.309402 -92.123571,42.30936 -92.123672,42.309308 -92.123847,42.309267 -92.124121,42.30927 -92.124164,42.309249 -92.124338,42.309209 -92.124439,42.309178 -92.124526,42.309157 -92.124786,42.309117 -92.124845,42.309118 -92.124888,42.309108 -92.12493,42.309109 -92.125075,42.3091 -92.125161,42.309101 -92.125278,42.309113 -92.125421,42.309146 -92.125463,42.309169 -92.125506,42.309169 -92.125693,42.309214 -92.125793,42.309226 -92.125936,42.30926 -92.125994,42.30926 -92.126137,42.309284 -92.126181,42.309295 -92.126368,42.309297 -92.126455,42.309309 -92.126512,42.30931 -92.126541,42.309331 -92.126583,42.309343 -92.126625,42.309365 -92.126684,42.309376 -92.126756,42.309398 -92.126827,42.309432 -92.12687,42.309432 -92.126912,42.309443 -92.127056,42.309445 -92.127173,42.309436 -92.12726,42.309437 -92.127317,42.309459 -92.127359,42.309459 -92.127403,42.30947 -92.127705,42.309474 -92.127762,42.309485 -92.127834,42.309486 -92.127878,42.309498 -92.12795,42.309509 -92.128036,42.309531 -92.128078,42.309554 -92.12812,42.309564 -92.128192,42.309598 -92.128512,42.309687 -92.128694,42.309732 -92.128822,42.309777 -92.128995,42.309811 -92.129309,42.30989 -92.129353,42.309911 -92.12941,42.309923 -92.129482,42.309955 -92.129524,42.309967 -92.129647,42.310029 -92.129725,42.310076 -92.129781,42.31012 -92.129923,42.31025 -92.130007,42.310391 -92.130034,42.310422 -92.130048,42.310455 -92.130103,42.310552 -92.130117,42.310585 -92.130146,42.310617 -92.130187,42.310682 -92.130214,42.310714 -92.13027,42.310843 -92.130325,42.310941 -92.130353,42.310962 -92.130396,42.311005 -92.130437,42.31107 -92.130465,42.311134 -92.130492,42.311167 -92.130535,42.311243 -92.130561,42.311318 -92.130561,42.31135 -92.130574,42.311393 -92.13057,42.311618 -92.130606,42.311723 -92.130623,42.311778 -92.130592,42.31186 -92.130591,42.311902 -92.130601,42.311935 -92.130599,42.312059 -92.130609,42.312092 -92.130608,42.312125 -92.130619,42.312158 -92.130618,42.312191 -92.130639,42.312224 -92.13065,42.312258 -92.130671,42.312283 -92.130682,42.312316 -92.130703,42.312341 -92.130735,42.312416 -92.13078,42.312482 -92.130845,42.312565 -92.130909,42.312657 -92.13092,42.31269 -92.130941,42.312724 -92.130951,42.312757 -92.130973,42.312782 -92.131027,42.312865 -92.131103,42.312949 -92.131167,42.313032 -92.131178,42.313065 -92.131221,42.313115 -92.131286,42.313174 -92.13133,42.3132 -92.131352,42.313225 -92.131385,42.313241 -92.131441,42.313292 -92.131484,42.313325 -92.131506,42.313351 -92.131572,42.313393 -92.131648,42.313459 -92.131832,42.313668 -92.131962,42.313794 -92.131995,42.313819 -92.132105,42.313961 -92.132137,42.313986 -92.132159,42.314011 -92.132203,42.314028 -92.132225,42.314053 -92.132245,42.314144 -92.132243,42.31421 -92.132253,42.314277 -92.132252,42.31431 -92.132326,42.314423 -92.132358,42.3144 -92.132411,42.314424 -92.132461,42.314478 -92.132481,42.314518 -92.13248,42.314549 -92.132491,42.31458 -92.13249,42.314611 -92.13253,42.314743 -92.132579,42.314829 -92.132641,42.314908 -92.132671,42.314963 -92.13271,42.315017 -92.132751,42.315103 -92.132761,42.315135 -92.132761,42.315165 -92.132749,42.315196 -92.132767,42.31529 -92.132788,42.315352 -92.132787,42.315408 -92.132786,42.315461 -92.132774,42.315491 -92.132771,42.315624 -92.132759,42.315655 -92.132738,42.315678 -92.132727,42.315708 -92.132726,42.315739 -92.132716,42.315771 -92.132715,42.315802 -92.132703,42.31584 -92.132703,42.315871 -92.132691,42.315902 -92.132649,42.315948 -92.132617,42.316002 -92.132605,42.316033 -92.132615,42.316065 -92.132615,42.316095 -92.132623,42.316126 -92.132737,42.316268 -92.132768,42.316291 -92.132767,42.316322 -92.132782,42.316339 -92.132817,42.3164 -92.132837,42.316424 -92.132847,42.316455 -92.132867,42.316487 -92.132877,42.316518 -92.132897,42.316541 -92.132908,42.316572 -92.132907,42.316603 -92.132937,42.316658 -92.132946,42.316689 -92.132987,42.316737 -92.133007,42.316775 -92.133079,42.316846 -92.133109,42.316901 -92.13316,42.316956 -92.133222,42.317011 -92.133241,42.317035 -92.133377,42.31709 -92.133408,42.317107 -92.133428,42.31713 -92.133423,42.317355 -92.133441,42.317448 -92.133462,42.317511 -92.133482,42.31755 -92.133492,42.317581 -92.133522,42.317636 -92.133531,42.317667 -92.133561,42.317722 -92.133601,42.317847 -92.133621,42.317878 -92.13362,42.317908 -92.133608,42.317939 -92.133767,42.317866 -92.133763,42.318028 -92.133781,42.318153 -92.133803,42.31818 -92.133814,42.318242 -92.13384,42.318305 -92.133874,42.318362 -92.133896,42.318389 -92.133931,42.3184 -92.133958,42.318426 -92.133972,42.318453 -92.133972,42.318484 -92.133997,42.318578 -92.13401,42.318604 -92.134037,42.31863 -92.134051,42.318662 -92.134071,42.318689 -92.134105,42.318704 -92.134127,42.31873 -92.134173,42.318851 -92.134206,42.318909 -92.134243,42.318955 -92.134288,42.318998 -92.134474,42.319199 -92.134488,42.31923 -92.134517,42.319268 -92.13459,42.319388 -92.134617,42.319414 -92.134658,42.319498 -92.134693,42.319555 -92.134779,42.319708 -92.13482,42.319766 -92.134827,42.319797 -92.134853,42.31985 -92.134939,42.319979 -92.135015,42.320056 -92.135068,42.320096 -92.135086,42.32013 -92.135085,42.320163 -92.1351,42.320223 -92.135126,42.320255 -92.135146,42.32027 -92.135162,42.320297 -92.135258,42.320397 -92.135355,42.320484 -92.13539,42.320509 -92.135487,42.320559 -92.13554,42.320607 -92.135583,42.320653 -92.135601,42.32068 -92.135671,42.320754 -92.135687,42.320781 -92.135715,42.320801 -92.135731,42.320828 -92.135907,42.320976 -92.13604,42.321083 -92.136153,42.321124 -92.136171,42.321158 -92.13618,42.321191 -92.136179,42.321225 -92.136221,42.321311 -92.136239,42.321338 -92.136292,42.321379 -92.136502,42.321587 -92.136527,42.321607 -92.136599,42.321635 -92.136634,42.321655 -92.136652,42.321681 -92.136676,42.321748 -92.136708,42.321798 -92.136764,42.321856 -92.13678,42.321883 -92.136913,42.32199 -92.136931,42.322017 -92.137009,42.322084 -92.137071,42.322118 -92.137106,42.322145 -92.137124,42.322172 -92.137132,42.322205 -92.137148,42.322238 -92.137184,42.322265 -92.137298,42.322393 -92.137376,42.322461 -92.137411,42.322474 -92.137579,42.322575 -92.137694,42.322656 -92.13777,42.322689 -92.137834,42.322731 -92.137862,42.322758 -92.137896,42.322778 -92.13795,42.322786 -92.138012,42.322826 -92.138142,42.322934 -92.138179,42.322948 -92.138205,42.322968 -92.138241,42.322981 -92.138286,42.322989 -92.138364,42.323016 -92.138445,42.32305 -92.138542,42.323111 -92.138711,42.323153 -92.138814,42.323156 -92.138901,42.323168 -92.138973,42.323184 -92.139044,42.323207 -92.139085,42.323225 -92.139116,42.32324 -92.139197,42.323268 -92.139232,42.323274 -92.13934,42.323318 -92.139745,42.323393 -92.139867,42.3234 -92.14007,42.323429 -92.140156,42.323436 -92.140265,42.323437 -92.140345,42.323448 -92.140431,42.323466 -92.14051,42.323499 -92.140618,42.323538 -92.140749,42.323551 -92.140966,42.323607 -92.141261,42.323664 -92.141349,42.323676 -92.141384,42.323687 -92.141449,42.323699 -92.14158,42.323711 -92.141885,42.323715 -92.141994,42.323721 -92.142189,42.323756 -92.142318,42.323768 -92.142427,42.323797 -92.142624,42.323828 -92.142713,42.323823 -92.142963,42.323886 -92.143149,42.323913 -92.143237,42.323932 -92.143318,42.323957 -92.143399,42.323988 -92.14343,42.324006 -92.143487,42.324025 -92.143518,42.324043 -92.143558,42.324055 -92.143663,42.324111 -92.143688,42.324132 -92.143719,42.32416 -92.143886,42.324282 -92.143919,42.324313 -92.143983,42.324356 -92.144047,42.324393 -92.144078,42.324417 -92.144336,42.324505 -92.1444,42.324542 -92.14454,42.324654 -92.144716,42.324894 -92.144772,42.324955 -92.144836,42.324998 -92.144995,42.32509 -92.145156,42.325164 -92.145237,42.325195 -92.145476,42.32533 -92.145596,42.325422 -92.1457,42.325484 -92.145781,42.325527 -92.145933,42.325589 -92.146046,42.325645 -92.146069,42.325705 -92.146068,42.325735 -92.146092,42.32576 -92.146132,42.325778 -92.146227,42.325845 -92.1463,42.325882 -92.146372,42.325913 -92.146404,42.325938 -92.146605,42.326048 -92.146684,42.326073 -92.146725,42.326092 -92.146765,42.326105 -92.146798,42.326123 -92.14687,42.326148 -92.146958,42.326167 -92.147048,42.326168 -92.147145,42.326163 -92.147226,42.326164 -92.147267,42.326171 -92.147339,42.326236 -92.147513,42.326303 -92.147777,42.326429 -92.147821,42.326446 -92.147865,42.326447 -92.14791,42.326456 -92.147954,42.326456 -92.147998,42.326465 -92.148108,42.326507 -92.148141,42.326524 -92.148163,42.32655 -92.14836,42.326659 -92.148404,42.32666 -92.148449,42.326652 -92.148493,42.326653 -92.148526,42.32667 -92.148569,42.326761 -92.148579,42.326794 -92.148601,42.326819 -92.148744,42.326845 -92.148789,42.326846 -92.148833,42.326854 -92.148877,42.326871 -92.148921,42.32688 -92.148952,42.326897 -92.149028,42.326964 -92.14905,42.326989 -92.149049,42.327022 -92.149126,42.327088 -92.149159,42.327105 -92.149203,42.327114 -92.149236,42.327131 -92.149379,42.327174 -92.149479,42.327191 -92.149655,42.327235 -92.149699,42.327252 -92.149754,42.32726 -92.14981,42.327261 -92.149895,42.32727 -92.150087,42.327273 -92.150287,42.327259 -92.150332,42.327251 -92.150398,42.327252 -92.150831,42.327224 -92.151164,42.327228 -92.151253,42.327237 -92.151297,42.327246 -92.151341,42.327246 -92.151386,42.327255 -92.15143,42.327256 -92.151485,42.327264 -92.151629,42.327274 -92.151817,42.327293 -92.152139,42.327297 -92.152228,42.32729 -92.152361,42.3273 -92.15245,42.327301 -92.152638,42.327319 -92.152859,42.327363 -92.152992,42.327373 -92.153136,42.327375 -92.153313,42.32741 -92.15339,42.327443 -92.153479,42.327492 -92.153516,42.32751 -92.153551,42.327519 -92.153586,42.327537 -92.153634,42.327538 -92.153669,42.327556 -92.153717,42.327556 -92.15386,42.327594 -92.154001,42.327666 -92.154035,42.327693 -92.154142,42.327738 -92.154178,42.327748 -92.154213,42.327766 -92.154261,42.327802 -92.154332,42.327838 -92.154401,42.327884 -92.154438,42.327902 -92.154543,42.327983 -92.15466,42.328046 -92.154719,42.328091 -92.154765,42.328144 -92.154883,42.328252 -92.154905,42.328279 -92.154941,42.328306 -92.154975,42.32836 -92.154999,42.328387 -92.155056,42.328502 -92.155079,42.328529 -92.155091,42.328556 -92.155126,42.328591 -92.155136,42.328618 -92.15537,42.328834 -92.155499,42.328959 -92.155557,42.329022 -92.155675,42.329129 -92.15578,42.32921 -92.155814,42.329246 -92.155851,42.329273 -92.155909,42.329336 -92.155979,42.329399 -92.156049,42.329452 -92.156143,42.329533 -92.156154,42.32956 -92.15619,42.329578 -92.156236,42.329614 -92.156319,42.329695 -92.156377,42.329739 -92.156517,42.329874 -92.156529,42.329901 -92.156553,42.329927 -92.15661,42.330017 -92.15662,42.330044 -92.156644,42.330071 -92.156656,42.330097 -92.156678,42.330124 -92.15669,42.330151 -92.156714,42.330178 -92.156724,42.330204 -92.156748,42.330231 -92.15676,42.330258 -92.156782,42.330284 -92.156794,42.33032 -92.156817,42.330347 -92.156885,42.330463 -92.156931,42.330578 -92.15693,42.330614 -92.156942,42.330641 -92.156925,42.331428 -92.156935,42.331491 -92.156948,42.331517 -92.156971,42.331544 -92.157029,42.331589 -92.157167,42.331719 -92.157196,42.331749 -92.157216,42.331779 -92.157245,42.331808 -92.157384,42.332037 -92.157427,42.332083 -92.157525,42.332202 -92.157543,42.332232 -92.157631,42.332314 -92.15767,42.332329 -92.157817,42.332441 -92.157875,42.332494 -92.157893,42.332524 -92.158078,42.332695 -92.158147,42.332748 -92.158186,42.33277 -92.158226,42.332785 -92.158255,42.332808 -92.158334,42.332838 -92.158413,42.332876 -92.15853,42.332944 -92.158764,42.333123 -92.158803,42.333146 -92.158843,42.333176 -92.158872,42.333206 -92.159127,42.333386 -92.159322,42.333506 -92.159351,42.333535 -92.159517,42.333648 -92.159636,42.333715 -92.159665,42.333745 -92.159703,42.333761 -92.159831,42.333858 -92.159869,42.333873 -92.159929,42.333918 -92.160084,42.334008 -92.160203,42.334069 -92.160262,42.334113 -92.160379,42.334181 -92.160526,42.334293 -92.160564,42.334316 -92.160593,42.334339 -92.160683,42.334384 -92.160898,42.334519 -92.160937,42.334534 -92.160966,42.334556 -92.161006,42.334572 -92.161134,42.334662 -92.161192,42.334714 -92.161259,42.334766 -92.1613,42.334789 -92.161329,42.334819 -92.161436,42.334879 -92.161495,42.334924 -92.161612,42.334991 -92.161672,42.335037 -92.161701,42.335067 -92.161866,42.335179 -92.161984,42.335224 -92.162063,42.335247 -92.162103,42.335255 -92.162142,42.33527 -92.162171,42.335293 -92.162181,42.335323 -92.16229,42.335371 -92.162641,42.335563 -92.162712,42.335609 -92.16294,42.335729 -92.163049,42.335775 -92.16312,42.335812 -92.163168,42.33583 -92.163204,42.335849 -92.163241,42.335859 -92.163386,42.335923 -92.163477,42.33597 -92.163664,42.336113 -92.162248,42.33718 -92.160963,42.338149 -92.160811,42.338256 -92.160649,42.338354 -92.160479,42.338444 -92.1603,42.338525 -92.159617,42.338751 -92.157873,42.338913 -92.157549,42.338938 -92.157224,42.338952 -92.156973,42.338955 -92.153683,42.338952 -92.15334,42.338956 -92.152975,42.338972 -92.15261,42.338998 -92.15246,42.339014 -92.152456,42.338671 -92.152451,42.3383 -92.152444,42.33768 -92.152391,42.333372 -92.152351,42.330106 -92.152336,42.329948 -92.152307,42.329791 -92.152263,42.329636 -92.152204,42.329484 -92.152177,42.329427 -92.152132,42.329334 -92.152046,42.329189 -92.151946,42.329049 -92.151834,42.328914 -92.15171,42.328785 -92.151573,42.328663 -92.151426,42.328548 -92.151268,42.328441 -92.151056,42.328318 -92.150925,42.328253 -92.150741,42.328173 -92.15055,42.328102 -92.150352,42.328041 -92.15015,42.32799 -92.148237,42.327567 -92.148234,42.327143 -92.148109,42.32692 -92.147736,42.326676 -92.146558,42.326399 -92.146248,42.326404 -92.145876,42.326689 -92.145749,42.327016 -92.143211,42.326454 -92.142271,42.326242 -92.137763,42.326234 -92.132934,42.326185 -92.123152,42.326184 -92.114017,42.326235 -92.114035,42.326125 -92.113982,42.325989 -92.113952,42.325928 -92.113911,42.32586 -92.113841,42.325781 -92.113759,42.325732 -92.113728,42.325707 -92.1136,42.325566 -92.113584,42.325535 -92.11356,42.32551 -92.113529,42.325419 -92.113531,42.325322 -92.113544,42.325153 -92.113552,42.325122 -92.113555,42.324989 -92.113549,42.32494 -92.113568,42.324844 -92.113568,42.324813 -92.113636,42.324662 -92.113674,42.324468 -92.113684,42.324372 -92.113686,42.324244 -92.113695,42.324208 -92.113695,42.324171 -92.11375,42.32396 -92.113751,42.323911 -92.113744,42.323881 -92.113745,42.323839 -92.113737,42.323808 -92.113737,42.323777 -92.113668,42.323638 -92.113627,42.323587 -92.113611,42.323556 -92.113604,42.323525 -92.113624,42.323368 -92.113651,42.323269 -92.113678,42.323213 -92.113697,42.323113 -92.113698,42.323043 -92.113676,42.322975 -92.113642,42.322911 -92.113626,42.322868 -92.113562,42.322741 -92.113538,42.322672 -92.113485,42.322414 -92.113487,42.322283 -92.113472,42.322226 -92.113456,42.322201 -92.113457,42.322132 -92.113435,42.321957 -92.113437,42.321888 -92.113448,42.321813 -92.113466,42.321744 -92.113475,42.321675 -92.113485,42.321638 -92.113502,42.321613 -92.113503,42.321582 -92.11353,42.321513 -92.11355,42.321376 -92.113552,42.321269 -92.113522,42.321131 -92.113466,42.320974 -92.11339,42.320682 -92.113339,42.320556 -92.113319,42.320532 -92.113269,42.320445 -92.113238,42.320422 -92.113206,42.320366 -92.113186,42.320343 -92.113167,42.320296 -92.113137,42.320241 -92.113116,42.320162 -92.11311,42.320045 -92.1131,42.319997 -92.113101,42.319959 -92.11309,42.319927 -92.113096,42.319646 -92.113108,42.319615 -92.113109,42.319576 -92.113121,42.319545 -92.113125,42.319364 -92.113115,42.319325 -92.113115,42.319294 -92.113085,42.319232 -92.113044,42.319169 -92.113014,42.319113 -92.112869,42.318994 -92.112775,42.31897 -92.112714,42.318883 -92.112703,42.318852 -92.112684,42.31882 -92.112706,42.31875 -92.112727,42.318719 -92.112856,42.318635 -92.112921,42.318549 -92.112933,42.318518 -92.112933,42.318487 -92.112943,42.318456 -92.112945,42.318393 -92.112957,42.31833 -92.112958,42.3183 -92.11297,42.318268 -92.113023,42.318191 -92.113112,42.318107 -92.11312,42.318083 -92.113102,42.317988 -92.113071,42.317871</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

And make a new file that only include the Placemarks with a GEOID10 that is in this list (eligible.txt):

```
190130028003089
190130028003087
190130028003086
190130028003085
190130028003084
190130028003082
190130028003057
190130028003044
190130028003043
190130028003042
190130028003041
190130028003031
190130028003030
190130028003028
190130028003027
190130028003023
190130028003022
190130028003021
190130028003020
190130028003018
190130028003016
190130028003009
190130028003003
190130028003001
190130028001119
190130028001118
190130028001103
190130028001095
```

Here's my attempt at a hack, many thanks to [James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162356/james-brown) for inspiring me to read about awk.

./bensawk < eligible.txt

#!/bin/bash 
    while read line; do
     awk -v p="$line" '
    // { d=1; b=""; }         # d is delete, b is buffer, reset both
    { b=b $0 (/</Placemark>/?"":ORS) }  # gather data to d
    /p/ {d=0}  # If match set d=0
    /</Placemark>/ && d=0 { print b }  # if line matches print b
    ' sample.kml >> out
    done

Comment: To put the question another way and perhaps clearer is:  I want to remove the placemark entries in the sample.kml file that don't have a matching GEO10ID in the file: eligible.txt.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use and xml aware tool for this task.  with `xmllint`

```
$ echo 'cat //*[local-name()="SimpleData"][@*[local-name()="name" and .="GEOID10"]]/text()' | 
  xmllint --shell file.xml | 
  sed -n '2~2p'

190130027002051
190130028003066
190130028003114
```

Comment: I think that I was unclear in my question.  I wanted to remove the placemark entries in the sample.kml file that didn't have a matching GEO10ID in the file eligible.txt.  I believe that this answer does is prints out all of the matching GEO10ID's in the sample.txt file.

Comment: My fault, I did not read the question carefully.  Still though, handling the nested xml structure with plain text tools are error prone.  If you can ensure formatting one tag per line and assuming tags don't exist at multiple levels perhaps it will work,

Comment: I'm really quite unfamiliar with what is out there.  the awk snippet `b=b $0 (/</Placemark>/?"":ORS)` was the first I'd seen that allows you to change the end of record from newline to something else, that what got me going on it.  I don't know how to get xmllint to select everything from <placemark> to </placemark> then search it for one of the strings in that file and if it is present print it to the new kml file.